# CrossJoin Rules in MDX Query

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cross-join

I Want to Create an MDX Query Builder with javascript and I need a rules to check is query need for `CrossJoin` or `Union` . i find [mdx-js](https://github.com/matthelm/mdx-js) but this library has not implement of `CrossJoin` so i want to Add this feature to `mdx-js.for example i have some dimension like this on  columns:

```
COLUMNS: [Aircraft].[Aircraft Type].[Type]
         [Altitude].[Altitude]
         [Aircraft].[Aircraft Engines].[Engines]
```

so how to decide when write and use crossjoin or union.

Answer (score 1):

Between different hierarchies and levels, you cannot use a `Union` is MDX, as all parameters to `Union` must have the same dimensionality. You could cross join these in case you want to see all combinations of these e. g. in the rows or columns.

Comment: So for this i can use `CorssJoin([Aircraft].[Aircraft Type].[Type],[Altitude].[Altitude],[Aircraft].[Aircraft Engines].[Engines])`

Comment: Yes. By the way, there is an alias for cross join in MDX which is ``*`. I. e. your `CrossJoin([Aircraft].[Aircraft Type].[Type],[Altitude].[Altitude],[Aircraft].[Aircraft Engines].[Engines])` can equivalently be written `[Aircraft].[Aircraft Type].[Type] * [Altitude].[Altitude] * [Aircraft].[Aircraft Engines].[Engines]`